# postfix filter "Do you want to have more lovers?"

Tags: postfix, spam-filter

My postfix is currently set up to check email content and reject by keywords. However, I can't think of a good way to block this kind of emails:

```
Return-Path: <gievcyopa@beamtele.com>
Delivered-To: xxx
Received: from beamtele.com (unknown [183.82.3.184])
    by XXX (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3FCAACD1FDD
    for XXX; Tue, 15 Dec 2015 13:09:36 +0800 (HKT)
From: Jilli M. Gillenwater <gievcyopa@beamtele.com>
To: xxx
Subject: Do you want to have more lovers?
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 10:39:34 +0530
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="Windows-1252"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Message-Id: <20151215050936.3FCAACD1FDD@xxx>
```

Good d̞ay my b̻oy .
are you
availaḃl͒e? I'm 
realֱly h~rny and 
want to h00ku֨p 
t֧onight! s֯en̗d a 
mٌsg so we can 
meet!!
M͐y 
nic̽knͧame is 
**Jilli88** :P
My account is 
here: http://upqepohh.yoursexychick.ru

Comment: And why don't you install an antispam ? All the free/paid antispams know to discard these emails.

Comment: We used spam blacklist sometime ago, but that created another problem. Even though all spams are blocked (which is good), some legitimate emails sent from those domains are also blocked (which is bad). Our users complained a lot when this happened.

Comment: Received: from beamtele.com (unknown [183.82.3.184])   this tells me that FCrDNS checks would have stopped this one.   From my /etc/postfix/postfix_client_blacklist:   
/^unknown$/  REJECT FCrDNS Failure